# what is .profile~ (not .profile)

Tags: 13.04, .profile

I was trying to uninstall NVM, and saw I have a .profile~ file as well .profile -  both have different content.

what is the different between them? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a backup copy created by a text editor. It is not used for anything.

Comment: Backup copies might be useful though.

Comment: it can be used to 'restore'  the editor session if theres some major crash.